# No response from API

Tags: javascript, vba, api, velo

I have created an API call in excel to get data from a Wix database.

The call:

```
     Dim http As Object, JSON As Object
     Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
     http.Open "GET", "https://username.wixsite.com/mysite/_functions/Functionname", False
     http.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "myauthkey"
     http.Send
     MsgBox (http.responseText)
```

The javascript http backend file on Wix:

```
    import { ok, notFound, serverError } from 'wix-http-functions';
    import wixData from 'wixdata';

    export function get_Wixdata() {
    let options = {
    "headers": {
       "content-type": "application/json"
    }
    };
    return wixData.query("wix data collection name")
     .find()
     .then(results => {
        if (results.items.length > 0) {
            options.body ={
            "items": results.items
         }
         return ok(options);
       }
     })
    }
```

I tested the call (without authorisation) on JSON place holder and it worked fine.

Just trying to debug what's happening as I am getting "" as a response.
Even if I enter the wrong API key I still get "", even a wrong url it's still a "" response.

I take it I am clearly way off the mark with what I am trying to do..

Comment: If I run your VBA code above as it is, with exactly the URL and authorization given there, I get an HTML code as response saying *"Error 404 occurred"*.

Comment: Is that not because the end point url is a default one and the auth key is made up? Or it might be to do with reference library, not too sure..

Comment: I was refering to you saying that whatever you put ther the response is empty even if you put a wrong url? Please clarify because it is not clear if you are telling us that your MSXML2.XMLHTTP is not working at all or if it is a issue with an specific URL.

Comment: Oh sorry, when I run the code using exactly submitted above it returns <!-- --> <!doctype html> wix error page and then 29 lines of html with some css references.
But when I run the code with the actual url and auth key it returns ""

Comment: In the second last line shouldn't there `})` be `});`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the VBA call, the header was not needed.

```
Dim https As Object, JSON As Object
Set https = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

With CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "end point url", False
    .send
    response = .responseText
End With
```

Comment: For easy investigation of the API side and confirming that the server side works I recommend a API development tool like https://www.postman.com this way it is easier to debug your API first. If that works properly then start developing your VBA code.

Comment: Are you able to see any reason why the http function wouldn't work? Trying to compare it to the hello world one but I'm not the best at js. I also tested the wixData query in the console and it does in fact return the table, so I know that part is correct. Just appears to be incorrect in the adding the query/'options' back to the call.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried put both headers in your request, like the following:

```
let headers = new Headers({ 
  'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
  'Authorization': '....' 
});
```

Comment: I am going to try create a JS http file to return "Hello" and not have it link to any tables etc. Then see if I can return that, might help me narrow down what the problem is